# How can I get more than 20 youtube search results using urllib?

Tags: python, web-scraping, youtube, youtube-data-api, urllib

I am trying to make a python script that fetches youtube channel URLs with a keyword input.
I'm using urlib to request the html of the search result page and then filtering out the channel IDs using RE.
I can't seem to find a way to get the script to fetch more than 20 results. Can anyone help me out here? Here's the code so far

```
import urllib.request
import re

search_keyword = input("Search Keyword \n")
html = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + search_keyword + "&sp=EgIQAg%253D%253D")
regex = r"\"channelId\": (\S{24})"
#print(html.read().decode())
ids = re.findall(r"\"channelId\"\:(\S{25})", html.read().decode())
idsLen = len(ids)
for i in range(idsLen):
    ids[i] = ids[i][1:]
    ids[i] = "https://www.youtube.com/channel/" + ids[i]
    print(ids[i])
```

I have looked up the urllib APIs to find something to get the job done, but I can't find anything related to it. I'm expecting someone can tell me how this can be achieved, with or without urllib.

Answer (score 1):

For more results you need to implement in some way [pagination](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/pagination), as you are working with the YouTube UI, [as I did](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/blob/c309312ad2369ba9287a2c882cf48992865dd229/search.php#L105-L117) in my [open-source](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API) [API](https://yt.lemnoslife.com).

Note that [you are anyway limited to 500 results](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/issues/4), if you use [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) [Search: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) endpoint or the YouTube UI.